# sort() and list has not attribute

Tags: python, list, attributeerror

I trying to get into programming and have a simple question:

If I have

```
def break_words(stuff):
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    ##Sorts the words."""
    words = break_words(words)
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(sentence):
    words = break_words(sentence)
    words = sorted(words)
    return words.pop(0)


sentence = "Tequila Mariachi Sangria"
print break_words(sentence)
print sort_words(sentence)
print print_first_word(sentence)
```

When I run it, my code is fine, while if I write

```
####################Test################

def break_words(stuff):
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    ##Sorts the words."""
    words = break_words(words)
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(sentence):
    words = break_words(sentence)
    words = sort_words(words)
    return words.pop(0)


sentence = "Tequila Mariachi Sangria"
print break_words(sentence)
print sort_words(sentence)
print print_first_word(sentence)
```

I will get

```
AttributeError: "list" object has no attribute "split"
```

both functions break_words and sort_words create list objects, so why do I get the error in my second case?

Answer (score 2):

`print_first_word(sentence)` calls

```
words = break_words(sentence)
```

Here, `words` is a list now, then it's passed to `sort_words(words)`, and next `break_words(words)`, in which calls

```
words = stuff.split(' ')
```

where `stuff` is a list, causing the error.

Comment: Thanks! this was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think that the second source code should be:

```
####################Test################

def break_words(stuff):
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    ##Sorts the words."""
    words = break_words(words)
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(sentence):
    words = sort_words(sentence)
    return words.pop(0)


sentence = "Tequila Mariachi Sangria"
print break_words(sentence)
print sort_words(sentence)
print print_first_word(sentence)
```

I changed `words = sort_words(words)` to `words = sort_words(sentence)`